# Invalidate a cookies for all users

Tags: javascript, caching, cookies

I have been asked to investage the ability of invalidating a certain cookie that has been created before May 1 (this is going to be done on May 1) so that the cookie is automatically updated because the hashing is changing.  Right now our cookies are set to last for 30 days.  Since cookie is located on the clients machines I can't think of any clean way of doing this for a number of reasons:

1. From what I know, I don't think there is a way to retrieve the creation or expiration data of a cookie in javascript.
2. Since the cookie is set for 30 days, whatever needs to happen would need to be present for 30 days

As of writing this one idea has come to mind.  The only thing I can think of, and it is such a hack, is basically at the whenever this switch needs to happen I add in a piece of code like:

```
var newHash = readCookie('new_hash');
if(newHash != 1)
{
    eraseCookie('hash');
    create_cookie('new_hash', 1, 60);//set this flag for 60 days 
}
```

So this should erase the hash cookie if the user has not be updated to the new hash and it should only do that every 60 days.  After 30 or so days I can remove this code as all user would have had their cookies refreshed to the new hash.

Is there a easier way to do this?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664132/1918287

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just make a cookie with a different name and start using that one instead? If your code no longer reads the old one the it basically doesn't exist.

Comment: That would require changing quite a few piece code of in both my backend PHP code and front-end javascript code.  Also, we have multiple sites that use this same cookie name that use the same backend codebase so that would require changing other sites too.

Comment: That's annoying. Perhaps the effort to rewrite it as a variable now will save hassle in the future? (If there isn't a nicer solution!)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the expires data as part of the new cookies value, as well as in the expiry parameter. Cookies without it will be the old cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try to read the incoming cookie, and if it doesn't fit your new hashing algorithm, invalidate it and redirect?