# How to invalidate all cookies in a web application

Tags: asp.net

How do I simply invalidate all kinds of cookies (including session, authentication, etc.).

Even if I remove all cookies using "browser cookie manager" and reset IIS, it appears like, it is still able to remember authentication cookie and logs me in automatically.

BTW, we are using SQL Server Session and Forms authentication.

If I leave the web application untouched for "certain" duration of time, it invalidates everything and redirects me to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a GUID or some other identifier available as the "current" value.

This value can be included in each of your cookie values. In your global handler, you can validate your cookies by ensuring that all of them have the same GUID as your server's value. If they don't match, then the cookies are "old" and are no longer any good. Proceed as you need from there (redirect to login screen, provide error message, etc.)

With FormsAuthentication, it's a little extra work to have a custom object in your ticket rather than using the out-of-the-box one-liners, but it's not too bad.

When you want to invalidate your users, just change the GUID on the server.

If you want to do this per-user, you'd store the GUID in your user table. If you only want to globally invalidate everyone at the same time, you can just have a single GUID in one place.